# Combining speaker drivers due to damaged component

Tags: diy, impedance, loudspeakers

I would appreciate some loudspeaker expertise.

Knocked over a speaker, magnet broke off of the tweeter.

Now I'm stuck in a DIY situation with the following components:

- One set of 2-system custom built speakers, minus one tweeter
- One set of 3-system commercial speakers with both woofers desintegrated

I'm guessing the tweeter is not repairable. 
*I would like to combine the speakers, but my poweramp only has 2 outputs.*

- 3-system speakers state they are 8 ohms, woofer back is also labeled 8 ohms
- 2-system drivers are labeled on the back as 4 ohms
- woofers are the same diameter

Can you think of a way to combine these, if it is possible in the first place?

Any additional info will be provided.

Comment: additionally, how hard would it be to just take the rubber from the rubber woofers and attach it onto foam-disintegrated cones?

Comment: It honestly sounds like a trip to your local authority recycling centre is in order, followed by a new purchase. Your initial question is unanswerable on the information given so far. Your follow-up comment is very very unlikely to be possible, certainly not as a DIY project.

Comment: to be honest if it was me I would probably reach for a microphone, a recording device and start a nice little bonfire in the back garden with those speakers.

Comment: I transfered the rubber. Got no clue what it does to sound. Don't really care that much, sounds all right to me. But thanks for advice. Let's close this for now. Will report if it fails at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but requires expertise. You need the specifications for all of the speaker components. Then you can build a passive filter that combines a woofer and tweeter, plus a new enclosure that's tuned to the frequency response of the components you've chosen.

It's much easier to replace the blown components with identical new ones.

Attaching a cone to a driver is also difficult, because you have to create a solid bond with only a small surface area you can glue. Then you have to solder the thin wires that go into the voice coil. There are shops that can do this for you (look for 'reconing' service, IIRC it's only done for expensive drivers as it costs a few hundred $).